# Reusing a require module in my angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I need to re-implement an old require module on a new angularjs app. The problem is, that I need another entry point so I load the scripts in my partial html. like this:

```
<!-- load needed scripts -->
<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl: "static/js/",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "./lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min",
            "d3": "./lib/d3/d3-3.4.11.min"
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="static/js/lib/require/require.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="model-chart-{{$index}}" data-ng-repeat="chart in chartData.getCharts()">
               {{ renderChart("#model-chart-" + $index, chart) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
       $scope.renderChart = function(selector, chartData) {
            console.log("render chart", selector, chartData, require);

            try {
                // this require only works once
                require(["scripts/util/renderChart"], function (renderChart) {
                    // console.log("data", data);
                    console.log(renderChart);
                    renderChart(
                        selector,
                        chartData,
                        -1
                    );
                });
            } catch (e) { $userinfo.setError("" + e); }
        }
```

The thing is that this works only once. Which means visiting the url works. Navigating back and revisit throws me an TypeError: object is not a function

How can I utilize the old require module. This old module is written by someone else so I do not want me to force into a rewrite :-)

EDIT:

For the moment I ended up using an iframe (*brrr*)